# Copy a virtualenv from host1 to host2, however, virtualenv on host2 show no installed packages

Tags: python, pip, copy, virtualenv

I copy a python virtualenv which holds many packages from host1 to host2. However, I activate the copied virtualenv on host2, and use `pip list` to show the installed packages, the installed packages disappeared.

I check the files in `<virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` the installed packages are still over there. So why `pip list` show nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the actual env, I would advice you to create a requirements file in the original env like this

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then copy that over the the second location and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```